# Capslock + semicolon is not working correctly

Tags: autohotkey

This is the expected behavior `Capslock+; = add semicolon to end of line`

```
Capslock & `;:: Send, {End}`;
```

This adds a semicolon at the current posistion, `End` doesn't seem to work. But if I  change it to

```
Capslock & a:: Send, {End}`;
```

It works as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Capslock & `;:: Send, {End}`; works for me.
Also i suggest against adding CapLock to your hotkey list as is it a special key used for changing letter case. Rather use ctrl, shift or alt.

Comment: @Dexter I have the same behaviour as Stephen. Placing the `;` between curly {'} brackets did not change it and combining it with the `Tab`key instead of `CapsLock`doesn't work either. Combining it with `Alt = !` or `Ctrl = ^` works perfectly again. Stephen, I hope this shows you that you are NOT the only one with this behaviour (I run AHK_L on Windows7x64), but I haven't found a solution either.

Answer (score 1):

The original

```
Capslock & `;:: Send, {End}`;
```

works for me with both AHK Basic and AHK_L. I don't know why its not working for you.

Alternatively you can try the SC keycode

```
Capslock & SC027::Send, {End}`;
```

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys

Comment: I have the same problem. On an Win8 machine it worked for a while but then stopped. I restarted AHK and all was good again. I switch keyboard layout a lot and thought somehow it was to blame but I am not sure of that.
Presently I have a Win7 machine, due to time travel complications, where the back tick trick doesn't work _at all_. SC027 works alright though.